# Cloning the template content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is an example of using `<template>` element.

In the below code, I just wrote a `div` element inside a `template` element

```
  <template id="tmpl">
     <div class="message">Hello, world!</div>
  </template>
```

And then I just used that `template` in the script below, a normal use case of `template`

```
<script>
  let elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.append(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
  document.body.append(elem);
</script>
```

We can see that `template.content` (basically a document fragment) was cloned before using it.
And explanation on [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/template-element) says that:
**Template content was cloned to reuse it multiple times**

My question is **why we can't reuse it without cloning?**. Can you give a deep insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `tmpl.content` is an element, and you can't append an element to another source when it is already appended to something. Try doing this instead:

```js
let elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.append(tmpl.content);
document.body.append(elem);
let elem2 = document.createElement("div");
elem2.append(tmpl.content);
document.body.append(elem2);
```

It won't work, because `tmpl.content` has already been appended to something else.